# CSS Grid: Force one grid item to fill as much space as possible without causing other grid items to overflow the container?

Tags: css, css-grid

Given a CSS grid layout with a **known fixed width and known fixed height** which contains two grid items—one with text of an unknown length and the other with an image—how can I make the image be *as large as possible* without causing the text to overflow the grid container's fixed height **using CSS only**?

I can calculate the required height using JavaScript or hard-code the width (as seen in the first two examples below), but I'm curious if this is possible using pure CSS. I've tried various combinations of `auto` and `1fr` and `minmax(0, 1fr)` for the grid items, but none of them seems to achieve what I'm looking for.

In the example code snippet below, the "magic width" for the third grid's image would be 178px, but my goal is to use CSS to automatically size the image grid item without resorting to JavaScript.

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  grid-template-areas: "text image";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.grid-item-text {
  grid-area: text;
}

.grid-item-image {
  grid-area: image;
}

.grid-item-image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.grid.example-1 .grid-item-image {
  width: 262px;
}

.grid.example-2 .grid-item-image {
  width: 201px;
}

.grid.example-4 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 410px;
  width: 180px;
}

.grid.example-1::after {
  content: "< Image grid item hard-coded to 262px";
}

.grid.example-2::after {
  content: "< Image grid item hard-coded to 201px";
}

.grid.example-3::after {
  content: "< How to make CSS grid automatically size the image as large as possible here without allowing the text to overflow the container? i.e. I don't want to use JS or hard-code 178px for the image grid item"
}

.grid.example-4::after {
  content: "< Text overflows container :(";
}
```

```html
<div class="grid example-1">
  <div class="grid-item-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in lacus venenatis nisi pellentesque varius. Etiam pretium metus non metus egestas dapibus. Cras id fringilla ipsum. Fusce sed finibus mi.
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid example-2">
  <div class="grid-item-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in lacus venenatis nisi pellentesque varius. Etiam pretium metus non metus egestas dapibus. Cras id fringilla ipsum. Fusce sed finibus mi. Sed scelerisque dui nec ipsum eleifend mattis. Integer ullamcorper malesuada lacus sit amet pharetra.
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid example-3">
  <div class="grid-item-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in lacus venenatis nisi pellentesque varius. Etiam pretium metus non metus egestas dapibus. Cras id fringilla ipsum. Fusce sed finibus mi. Sed scelerisque dui nec ipsum eleifend mattis. Integer ullamcorper malesuada lacus sit amet pharetra. Sed fringilla felis nec consequat porta.
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid example-4">
  <div class="grid-item-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in lacus venenatis nisi pellentesque varius. Etiam pretium metus non metus egestas dapibus. Cras id fringilla ipsum. Fusce sed finibus mi. Sed scelerisque dui nec ipsum eleifend mattis. Integer ullamcorper malesuada lacus sit amet pharetra. Sed fringilla felis nec consequat porta.
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note:* Although the text is of an unknown length, we can safely assume the text will never exceed the height of the parent container when it's at the full width of the parent container. In other words, the text will always allow *some room* for the image.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the image to stop expanding at the point where the text reaches full height of the container. This means you want to condition the height of one element on the height of its sibling. I don't think that's possible with CSS alone.

Comment: No, that’s never going to work. Recommend you change your design.